# How to configure listeners in ActiveMQ for postgres

Tags: java, jboss, activemq-classic

How to configure listeners in ActiveMQ for postgres.I am using Jboss with ActiveMQ combination.

modified in ejb-jar.xml file.

```
<enterprise-beans>
    <message-driven>
        <display-name>NamelListener</display-name>
        <ejb-name>NamelListener</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>com.deb.mdb.InternalListener</ejb-class>
        <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>          
        <activation-config>
            <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>IP_NAME</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
        </activation-config>
    </message-driven>
    .......
```

And modified ra.xml file in activemq.xml file

```
<adminobject>
     <adminobject-interface>javax.jms.Queue</adminobject-interface>
     <adminobject-class>org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue</adminobject-class>
     <config-property>
        <config-property-name>PhysicalName</config-property-name>
        <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
        <config-property-value>IP_NAME</config-property-value>
     </config-property>
  </adminobject>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above mentioned way we can do....There ware some some setup issue on my machine.After fix that it was working.